# HQs : plural of the abbreviation of "headquarters"

Tags: grammatical-number, abbreviations

According to the CambridgeGEL, *headquarters* has the same singular and plural form, but **HQs** is the plural of the abbreviation of "*headquarters*".

Aren't both statements contradictory? Apparently people use it as fallows:

*A company with one headquarters has an HQ. A company with two headquarters has two HQs*. According to Wiktionary, **hdqrs** (plural **hdqrs**).

Yet, does **h.q.** or **H.Q.** have a similar plural?

Comment: *PIN* → *personal identification* ***number***. *PINs* → *personal identification* ***numbers***. An *s* is added to an acronym to indicate its plurality, regardless of the spelling of the words that the acronym stands for.

Comment: In a way, of course they are. But don't confuse 'contradictory' with 'wrong'.  _That's English for you_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth _A company with one headquarters has an HQ. A company with two headquarters has two HQs_. According to Wiktionary, **hdqrs** (plural **hdqrs**). Yet, does **h.q.** or **H.Q.** have a similar plural?

Comment: Which company has *two* headquarters?

Comment: Isn't this a really good reason to swithch to HQ / HQs!

Comment: I have never seen headquarters with a plural meaning where it refers to two different administrative units. But when it does, two headquarters fine. And I highly doubt that one would need to abbreviate that....https://nymag.com/intelligencer/2018/11/a-question-for-amazon-how-many-headquarters-can-youhave.html

Comment: @WeatherVane Very few if any have more than one HQ but if you have multiple corporate clients you could say "I've visited the HQs of all my clients in the last year." since each client will have an HQ.